# HTML en google forms

Tags: html, google-forms

Es posible agragar HTML a google forms? 
mi intención es colocar un widget dado el siguiente código

```html
<!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "997269893725074", // Facebook page ID
            whatsapp: "+595984439000", // WhatsApp number
            telegram: "+595984439000", // Telegram bot username
            email: "ventas@puntohogar.com.py", // Email
            sms: "+595984439000", // Sms phone number
            call: "+595984439000", // Call phone number
            company_logo_url: "//scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/14051735_1021405514644845_2020736532428360264_n.jpg?oh=7c1ae61d74a5a12cc7fb164bd3ce111a&oe=59DECFA7", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
            greeting_message: "Consulta AQUI !", // Text of greeting message
            call_to_action: "Consulta AQUI !", // Call to action
            button_color: "#129BF4", // Color of button
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "facebook,whatsapp,telegram,sms,call,email" // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

ar un widget al formulario dado el siguiente código

```
<!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "997269893725074", // Facebook page ID
            whatsapp: "+595984439000", // WhatsApp number
            telegram: "+595984439000", // Telegram bot username
            email: "ventas@puntohogar.com.py", // Email
            sms: "+595984439000", // Sms phone number
            call: "+595984439000", // Call phone number
            company_logo_url: "//scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/14051735_1021405514644845_2020736532428360264_n.jpg?oh=7c1ae61d74a5a12cc7fb164bd3ce111a&oe=59DECFA7", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
            greeting_message: "Consulta AQUI !", // Text of greeting message
            call_to_action: "Consulta AQUI !", // Call to action
            button_color: "#129BF4", // Color of button
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "facebook,whatsapp,telegram,sms,call,email" // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desafortunadamente no es posible editar el código *html* de un *Google Form*, puedes manipular los datos de las respuestas enviadas usando [*La API de Google Forms*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) o bien la API de [*Google Spreadsheet*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) (claro está, si guardas las respuestas del formulario en una hoja de cálculo). Sin embargo, el código *html* como tal no puedes manipularlo.

Una opción que puedes elegir es crear una *Google App* y hacer desde cero tu Formulario, anexarle los campos y el código *javascript* que tu quieras (como el *widget* que quieres insertar) usando para ello [*HTMLService*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/).