# Expresión regular para validar un municipio de colombia

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-forms

Estoy realizando un formulario de Google en el cual quiero preguntarle al encuestado cual es el lugar de nacimiento, sin embargo tengo un problema pues la cantidad de opciones asciende hasta las **1123** una cantidad que causa que el formulario se ponga bastante pesado.

He pensado diferentes opciones y creo que la más viable es utilizar una expresión regular que me permita verificar si las personas están escribiendo nombres los cuales se encuentran dentro de las **1123**, intente usar Google Apps Script pero no pude encontrar nada que me fuera de utilidad.

Se que otra opción es dejar un código a cada municipio y que el usuario lo digite para validar que escriban un numero valido, pero quiero evitar a toda costa que el usuario tenga que recurrir a otra página diferente de el formulario de Google.

Dejo la lista de la cual hablo a contuacinon [municipios_y_departamentos](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTnS7bhQ1WJ-h8JIAaxpcuqe002fHNTgJX5iSnGtQ5Inm0pIu6OTv70OMgqwEO7DZH9pkaQcO_ZFpMf/pubhtml)

Agradezco si me proporcionan ideas de como solucionar este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un diseño de filtro descendente es lo que parece que podrías aplicar, donde primero preguntas la región, luego el departamento o distrito y por último el municipio. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras cuando te refieres a un filtro dependiente es programarlo ¿ mediante Google Apps Script ? ó utilizar las secciones para dejar un departamento en cada sección y que el usuario vaya a las posibles ( 32 departamentos ) 32 secciones que existen para este caso particular.
Muchas gracias por tu aporte :)

Answer (score 1):

No se puede usar Google Apps Script ni agregar JavaScript en la vista para responder un formulario de Google.

Por lo anterior, no se puede tener lista dependientes en formularios con una única sección,  pero es posible si pones una sección, por ejemplo,por cada uno de los departamentos, si esto te resultara impráctico seguramente deberás pensar en usar otra herramianta como podría ser usar Google Apps Script para crear una aplicación web

Relacionado

- [HTML en google forms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114027/65)
- [Lista desplegable dinámica en formulario de Google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/373784/65)

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms

Comment: Gracias, lamentablemente resulta impráctico realizarlo una sección por cada departamento ya que son 32 y esto sobrecargaría aún más el formulario.
Por lo tanto creo que la mejor opción como lo recomiendas es crear una Aplicación Web ó construir un complejo RegeX que realice tal filtro